# If number of rows in table is less than limit, it returns number of rows - 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 53 rows. My sql statement looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1 , 100`

It is showing me 52 rows instead of 53. What gives? Of course when I run:

`SELECT * FROM table`

It returns 53 rows as it should.

What is the best way to fix this, so that I can have a limit if I need it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `LIMIT x, y`, the first value is an *offset*. So `LIMIT 1, 100` means to *skip* the first 1 record, and show rows 2 through 101. To get the first 100 rows without skipping any, write `LIMIT 0, 100` or simply `LIMIT 100`.

Comment: I read tons of things about this. Thinking `x` was page. **Facepalm**